# Prove concerning planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I need to prove that in a planar graph with more than two vertexes at least a vertex with a maximum grade of five exists.

I know that planar graphs fulfill the relation $\#E \le 3\#V-6$, and relation $\#E \le 2\#V-4$ if there is no subgraph that is isomorphic to $K_{3}$. $\#E$ being the number of edges and $\#V = n$ being the number of vertexes.

Based on the statement that says $\sum_{i=1}^{n}gr(v_{i}) = 2\#E$ I have come up that for complete graphs $K_{n}$ the next relation must be fulfilled: $$n^{2}-4n+6\le 0$$ But I can not figure how to prove what it is asked to prove

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose all vertices have degree 6 or more. Then we have
$$
|E|\geq \frac{1}{2}\cdot 6 \cdot|V|=3|V|,
$$
since every edge contains two vertices. This clearly contradicts your inequality.

Comment: But does this correctly prove what is asked to prove at the beginning?

Comment: @Haritz Why do you believe not?

Comment: Perhaps this just proves that the initial statement is true for complete graphs?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying, complete graphs in general aren't planar, right? We want to show that if a graph is planar, then it has a point of degree $\leq 5$. Suppose it does not, then we reach a contradiction with a well-known formula.

Comment: OK. Cleared. Thank you @Jolien.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20990/discussion-between-haritz-and-jolien).